# Piping operator in c++

Tags: c++20, overloading

I wrote a simple piping operator in c++. I just wanted to make sure that my code was robust, modern c++ code, and made correct use of perfect forwarding.

Here's the code:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

//Accept an object on the left hand side and a function on the right
template <typename Any, typename... Args>
inline auto operator| (const Any& obj, std::invocable<Any> auto func){
    // Correct use of perfect forwarding??
    return func(std::forward<const Any&>(obj));
}

//Version for a functor which accepts a reference. Do I need to cover other cases?
template <typename Any, typename... Args>
inline auto operator| (Any& obj, std::invocable<Any&> auto func){
    return func(std::forward<Any&>(obj));
}
```

And here is how the user uses it:

```
int main() {
    auto x = std::vector{1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6};
    // Piping example 0
    auto y = 5 | [] (int x) {return x * 2;} 
               | [] (int x) {return x * 3;}
               ;
    
    std::cout << y << '\n';
    // Piping example 1
    x | [] (std::vector<int>& vec) -> std::vector<int>& {vec.push_back(7); return vec;};

    std::cout << x[6];
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to clean up the lambda syntax (I don't mind personally) and have a cleaner, neater syntax you can do:

```
namespace piping {
    template <typename T>
    auto push_back(const T& obj) {
        return [obj] (auto& vec) -> auto& {vec.push_back(obj); return vec;};;
    }
}

/* ... Some code */

int main() {
    auto x = std::vector{1 , 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 , 6};
    // A bit cleaner...
    x | piping::push_back(7);
}
```

Did I make correct use of modern c++ and perfect forwarding?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a worthwhile objective.  The syntax looks a bit clunky when we have to write lambdas inline like that, but you'll probably develop a library of useful filters (like standard Ranges ones) that look much more natural.

I don't think we've got the use of forwarding references quite right - and you'll be pleased to hear that fixing that should simplify the code a bit.

What we should do is use `typename Any&&`.  Although that looks like an rvalue-reference, it's actually a **forwarding reference** because `Any` is a template parameter.

`Any&&` allows the template parameter to bind to *either* lvalue *or* rvalue, so we just need the one function:

```
template <typename Any>
auto operator| (Any&& obj, std::invocable<Any> auto&& func) {
    return func(std::forward<Any>(obj));
}
```

(Note also the `auto&&` for `func`, so it can be a mutable functor if we want).

---

Having written that, I'm not so convinced that I like `operator|()` to be modifying its argument.  I would prefer `a | b` to leave `a` alone, and have to write `a |= b` when I intend `a` to be modified in place.

---

Minor points:

- There are headers included but not needed for the template:

  > ```
  > #include <vector>
  > #include <iostream>
  > #include <deque>
  > ```
- `inline` is implicit for a template function.
- We don't need to spell out the full return type for the "append 7" lambda in the example - `-> auto&` is easier.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback and explaining perfect forwarding!! I had never quite understood it until now... About the "inline" keyword, the compiler (-O3) seemed to be better at optimising my code when the "inline" was there??

Comment: I'm surprised by that.  If the `inline` is helpful, then continue using it.  I don't think it can do any harm.

Comment: It's worth searching the web for good articles on **perfect forwarding** and **forwarding references**.  Another good search term is **universal references**, which is the older term for this construct.

Comment: yes it surprised me as well. In fact both versions of my code inlined the function, but the version with "inline" straight up calculated everything at compile - time, while the version without inline had to call the lambda.

Comment: OOh - perhaps it would make sense to add `constexpr` to the declaration?  I'm not 100% sure about that, though - I'm just a beginner with `constexpr`.  IIRC, the lambda can also be declared `constexpr`, but I'm really walking on thin ice now...

Comment: No - constexpr doesn't really work (it would be up to the user to mark the lambda constexpr) - my piping operator just needs to do too many things at run-time to be constexpr. However, the compiler can do absolutely anything it wants as long as it does not have observable behaviour, so I think the "inline" just makes it a bit more transparent to the compiler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119430/discussion-between-cyrus-and-toby-speight).